# Variable or Field 'nameOfVariable' declared void no idea why :(

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock, void

I've googled and searched on various websites and I can not work out why I get the follow errors from one of my functions.

**error: variable or field 'ConnectClient' declared void**

**error: 'Socket' was not declared in this scope**

Both of those errors are for the line 38 of my code, which is the...

```
void ConnectClient(Socket _newConnection)
```

From what I understood from other posts asking about this question, it normally came down to inconsistencies with the header file (Which I'm NOT using for this little test) or they had a return type in the void function which I don't have.

NOTE: I've removed extra bits of code that relate to part of the game code, and stacks of commented out code which I was testing.  This program is a little test into winsock use

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>

using namespace std;
const int serverPort = 31337;
const int serverMaxClients = 10;
SOCKET serverSocket;
SOCKET clientSocketArray[serverMaxClients];   //should this have a -1 on it?

bool clientSlotTaken[serverMaxClients];
sockaddr clientSocketAddresses[serverMaxClients];

int FindFreePlayerSpot()
{
    for (int slotIndex = 0; slotIndex < serverMaxClients; slotIndex++)
    {
        if (clientSlotTaken[slotIndex] == false)
        {
            return slotIndex;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

void ConnectClient(Socket _newConnection)
{
    int slotIndex = FindFreePlayerSpot();
    if (slotIndex == -1)
    {
        closesocket(_newConnection);
        cout << "No player slots available, connection aborted"
    }
    else //Should have a connection
    {
        clientSocketArray[slotIndex] = _newConnection;
        if (clientSocketArray[slotIndex] == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            cout << "Client Connection Error - INVALID SOCKET " << WSAGetLastError();
        }
        else //Client should have connected
        {
            cout << "Client Connected on socket slot [" << slotIndex << "] from " << "\n";
            clientSlotTaken[slotIndex] = true;
        }
    }
}

void StartWinSock()
{
    WSADATA WsaDat;
    if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&WsaDat)!=0)
    {
        std::cout<<"WSA Initialization failed!\r\n";
        WSACleanup();
        system("PAUSE");
    }

    serverSocket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(serverSocket==INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::cout<<"Server Socket creation failed.\r\n";
        WSACleanup();
        system("PAUSE");
    }

    SOCKADDR_IN serverInf;
    serverInf.sin_family=AF_INET;
    serverInf.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
    serverInf.sin_port=htons(serverPort);

    if(bind(serverSocket,(SOCKADDR*)(&serverInf),sizeof(serverInf))==SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout<<"Unable to bind socket!\r\n";
        WSACleanup();
        system("PAUSE");
    }

    if(listen(serverSocket,SOMAXCONN)==SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout<<"Unable to Listen!\r\n";
        WSACleanup();
        system("PAUSE");
    }

    u_long iMode=1;
    ioctlsocket(serverSocket,FIONBIO,&iMode);
}


int main()
{
    playerShip = new PlayerShip;
    bool runningServer = true;

        cout << "Starting WinSock\n";
        StartWinSock();
        cout << "Running on port " << serverPort << "\n";


        while (true)
        {
            //Check for a connection
            Socket newConnection = accept(serverSocket,NULL,NULL);
            if (newConnection != SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                cout << "Incomming connection attempt";
                ConnectClient(newConnection);
            }
            Sleep(1);
        }


    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is the class `Socket` (note that capital `S` and lowercase `ocket`) defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void ConnectClient(Socket _newConnection)
{
    int slotIndex = FindFreePlayerSpot();
    if (slotIndex == -1)
    {
        closesocket(_newConnection);
        cout << "No player slots available, connection aborted"
    }
```

Two problems here.

1)It should be SOCKET, not Socket.

2) You're missing a semi-colon (;) at end of the cout statement above.

Fix those two errors above, the related compiler errors in main() and your code will at least compile.  As to whether it works or not...

Comment: FFFFFFFFFFFFUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU!!!!!!!!!  I hate it when I make those kind of mistakes >_<   Thanks for pointing it out :)